# Angular : passing data between components using service

Tags: angular, typescript

I work on Angular 4, onclick of one of the 'groups' its tile should be added to the list of 'favourites' (which is an array). For this I used `BehaviorSubject`. I am able to display `default message` on my `FavouriteComponent.html` but when I click on newMessage() from `GroupComponent.ts` the value in `FavouriteComponent.html` is not changing it remains `default message`. Please guide me where I went wrong or is there any other way to achieve my requirement.

DataService.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject("default message");
  currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  changeMessage(message: string) {
    this.messageSource.next(message)
  }

}
```

FavouriteComponent.ts

```
import { DataService } from "../data.service";
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: `
    {{message}}
  `
})
export class FavouriteComponent implements OnInit {

  message:string;

  constructor(private data: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.currentMessage.subscribe(message => this.message = message)
  }

}
```

GroupComponent.ts

```
import { DataService } from "../data.service";
@Component({
  selector: 'app-sibling',
  template: `
    {{message}}
    <button (click)="newMessage()">New Message</button>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./sibling.component.css']
})
export class GroupComponent implements OnInit {

  message:string;

  constructor(private data: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.currentMessage.subscribe(message => this.message = message)
  }

  newMessage() {
    this.data.changeMessage("new title to add")
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  private messageSource = new Subject<String>();

  constructor() { }

  public getMessage(): Observable<String> {
    return this.messageSource.asObservable();
  }

  public setMessage(message: String) {
    return this.messageSource.next(message);
  }

}
```

---

```
export class FavouriteComponent implements OnInit {

  message:string;

  constructor(private data: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.getMessage.subscribe(message => this.message = message)
  }

}
```

---

```
export class GroupComponent implements OnInit {

  message:string;

  constructor(private data: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.getMessage.subscribe(message => this.message = message)
  }

  newMessage() {
    this.data.setMessage("new title to add")
  }

}
```

Hope This helps

Comment: unnecessarily complicated

Answer (score 0):

Remove `currentMessage` and subscribe to `messageSource` (make it public)

Comment: I made messageSource public and did this, still new value is not going to FavouriteComponent. Any other idea?

this.data.messageSource.subscribe(message => this.message = message)

Comment: Can you create a Stackblitz example?

Comment: its blocked in my firm :( 

I am getting the new value in my service its only that it is not reflecting it to FavouriteComponent.