# how to pass boolean variable from one service to other service in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to pass a boolean value from one service to other service file , in that I am getting boolean value is undefined and I do not find any examples and documents related to it in angular, can anyone guide me to this

need to pass a boolean value from this file:

```
Auth.service.ts

public Data: boolean;

passValueFunction(){
this.Data =true
}
```

in this service file, i need to get that boolean value(Data variable in auth.service file) come from auth service file

```
second.service.ts

constructor(private authService: Authservice){
}

ngOninit(){
console.log(this.authService.Data)
}
```

in second service file, I am not getting the Data value as true. I want this.authService.Data = true in second service file. I do not have any idea why am getting this.authservice.Data= undefined.

Comment: `Data` isn't true until the `passValueFunction` is called...

Comment: calling this passValuFunction in my ts file

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. You need to call `passValueFunction` in a TypeScript file (or JavaScript file, I suppose), yes. I don't know why you have a `passValueFunction` defined. I don't know what the real use case is, so can't advise you on the course of action you should take. I was just pointing out the reason you are getting undefined when logging `this.authService.Data`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is about that your `second.service.ts` initiating earlier than function:

```
passValueFunction(){
  this.Data =true
}
```

called.
Here you can have a few different solutions in case what to you expect from this communication between services.
If you need to trigger some function in the `second.service.ts` only when `Data` value changed to `true` I suggest you to create an `Observable` or `BehaviorSubject` in the `Auth.service.ts` and subscribe on the value of this `Observable/BS` in the `second.service.ts`.

Comment: can you give me any code snippets or documentation

Comment: @Abi.D check this answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/50385699/6160479

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of how to do it. If you want to get the value from an outside component

**In service1.service.ts (or your auth service):**

```
export class Service1Service {

  public data = false;

  constructor() { }

  passValueFunction(){
    this.data =true
  }
}
```

**In service2.service.ts (or your second.service.ts):**

```
export class Service2Service {

  constructor(
    private service1: Service1Service
  ) { }

  getValue() {
    console.log(this.service1.data);
  }
}
```

**In the component using the 2nd service:**

```
    constructor(
    private service2: Service2Service,
    ){
    
  }

  // this method is promted by button
  async onTestAnything() {

    //this.service1.passValueFunction();  // add this method if you 1st want to set the bool using the passValueFunction() method

    this.service2.getValue();
  }
```

I am only using the 2nd service and the 2nd service is reading the data bool from the 1st service, thus the bool has been passed on